# Excel VBA - Custom Filter using Named Range

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column of data on a worksheet, contained within a very large workbook that I am working on, named `Vendor` and I want to write a macro in VBA which allows me to filter by a particular vendor, say `Vendor A`.

So far I have this:

```
Sub filterVendor()
'
' filterVendor Macro
'

'
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A:$BB").AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:= _
        "Vendor A"

End Sub
```

The problem I have is that the location of the `Vendor` column may well change - as other columns are added and/or deleted before it, causing it to shift accordingly - and I want to know if it is possible to reference this particular column/block of data to save the macro becoming useless.

Ideally, I would reference the range (`vendor` is what I would like to call the named range) so that, no matter what happens to the structure of the worksheet, the filter will always work correctly when the macro is run.

How can this be done?

**FURTHER INFO:**

I suspect that the `Field:` criteria is causing the problem as this appears to absolutely define the column to be filtered; even though I have specified that the `Vendor` column is named `vendor` as a named range, and even though the named range reference moves along with said `Vendor` column, the column that is filtered always lies at the position specified in `Field:`.  How can this be fixed in order to work how I want it to?

I have tried:

```
...Field:=Range("vendor")
```

and

```
...Field:=(Range("vendor"))
```

but both of these cause an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting challenge! I tackled this by:

- Using a named `Range`, "Vendor", as you describe (I think)
- Writing a small helper function, `DoesVendorExist`, that ensures the named `Range` "Vendor" exists
- Writing another small helper function, `VendorColNum`, that returns the column number of "Vendor"
- Applying the `.Autofilter` based on the number returned by `VendorColNum`

Here is a screenshot of the (admittedly small) workbook I tested on:

[image: start]

Here are the helper functions and a slightly-modified `filterVendor2` subroutine:

```
Option Explicit
Sub filterVendor2()

Dim DataSheet As Worksheet
Dim VendorCol As Long

'set references up-front
Set DataSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("data")

'...
'doing other stuff
'...

'here we make sure a named range called Vendor exists
If Not DoesVendorExist(ThisWorkbook) Then
    MsgBox ("Dangit! There is not a named range Vendor in this workbook! Exiting...")
    Exit Sub
End If

'define the vendor column
VendorCol = VendorColNum(DataSheet)

'here we make sure the Vendor named range is not empty
If VendorCol = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Bummer! The named range Vendor was Nothing on DataSheet, exiting...")
    Exit Sub
End If

'otherwise, let's do some filtering!
DataSheet.Range("$A:$BB").AutoFilter Field:=VendorCol, Criteria1:="SnookerFan"

'...
'doing other cool stuff and finishing up
'...

End Sub

'INPUT  : pass this function the worksheet on which the Vendor range is defined
'OUTPUT : the column number that the Vendor range exists in
'SPECIAL: if the Vendor Range is nothing, return 0
Public Function VendorColNum(Sheet As Worksheet) As Long

'if the Vendor range is missing, return 0 and exit
If Sheet.Range("Vendor") Is Nothing Then
    VendorColNum = 0
    Exit Function
End If

'otherwise, we return a real column number
VendorColNum = Sheet.Range("Vendor").Column

End Function

'INPUT  : pass this function the workbook we'd like to check for Vendor
'OUTPUT : true/false... does Vendor exist?
'SPECIAL: none
Public Function DoesVendorExist(Book As Workbook) As Boolean

Dim Nm As Name

'assume false, test each name and flip the flag if Vendor is found
'assume false, test each name and flip the flag if Vendor is found
DoesVendorExist = False
For Each Nm In Book.Names
    If UCase(Nm.Name) = UCase("vendor") Then '<~ error was here, did not paste over .Name
        DoesVendorExist = True
        Exit Function
    End If
Next Nm

End Function
```

Finally, this is the resulting filtered `Range`. You should find that adding or removing columns on the data sheet does not wreck the code.

[image: end]

**Edit:** my apologies as the error on checking the named range was a sloppy copy/paste as I worked through the issue myself. I have updated the code above and highlighted the error (was checking `Nm` to see if it matched "Vendor", should have been checking `Nm.Name` to see if it matched `UCASE("vendor")`.

Comment: A spectacular answer (and I'm glad you liked my challenge)! One thing I changed was to remove/comment out `IF Not DoesVendorExist(ThisWorkbook) Then` section as it kept resulting in an error (even though I had defined - and re-redefined `vendor` as a named range!).  As you state, I can confirm that I have inserted a column, applied the filter and it works very well! Any ideas why the "validation" section hadn't worked even thought I'd defined the range?  If not, then don't worry as it works well - just curious. Thanks again.

Comment: The error here was my bad, and I have modified my answer above with a full correction (in the **Edit:** post-script). In a nutshell, I was being a dummy last night as I copied over text and edited it on the web, and as such mistakenly left the `If` statement checking `Nm` when it was checking `Nm.Name` on my local workbook. Glad this worked for you though!

Comment: I see, thank you.  Unfortunately, this brings up the `Dangit!...` error message.  However, if I comment out the `If Not DoesVendorExist(ThisWorkbook) Then` method, then it runs perfectly...any ideas why this is?

Comment: Hmm... when I adjusted it locally and re-ran the code I was able to blow right through that error message. Do me a favor and double-check the `DoesVendorExist` function that you copied over, is it using `UCase` on both `Nm.Name` and "vendor"?

Comment: Update: I resolved it because the conversion to uppercase `If Nm.Name = UCase("vendor") Then` was causing the problem as my range name is `vendor` (lowercase).  This appears to have resolved it all now - thanks again!

Comment: Glad we got it dialed in :)

Answer (score 1):

**Autofilter** likes one-based single-dimensioned arrays, so we build and apply this type of array:

```
Sub FilterMyData()
    Dim ary(), N As Long, i As Long

    N = Range("Vendors").Count
    ReDim ary(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        ary(i) = Range("Vendors")(i).Value
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:BB")
        .AutoFilter Field:=23, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I have modified it slightly but it results in a type mismatch error.  Again, it appears to be the `Field:=` property that is causing the error. Here is the modified code: `Sub FilterMyData() Dim ary(), N As Long, i As Long

    N = Range("vendor").Count
    ReDim ary(1 To N)
    For i = 1 To N
        ary(i) = Range("vendor")(i).Value
    Next i

    With ActiveSheet.Range("A:BB")
        .AutoFilter Field:=21, Criteria1:=ary, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    End With
End Sub`

Comment: Column U is where the data resides, yes - the problem is that if/when the `Vendor` data moves, the `Field:=` variable doesn't - is there a way to set `Field:=` to focus on named range `vendor` and not a specific, static column? `Vendor` column has good, consistent data (text only).

Comment: Now I understand.........if the **Vendors** range has been moved, the macro must be re-run.

Comment: Yes, I know this but the problem is that the macro does not run as it keeps resulting in a type mismatch error.  Furthermore, where do I specify that I wish to filter `Vendor A` from the `Vendors` list, as per my original question?

Comment: I can't replicate the *Type mismatch* ........to pick one or more vendors from the **Vendors** array, I would use a *UserForm*, and then apply the sub-set to the filter.

Answer (score -3):

Are you using MS Excel version 2010? If so, you can use the built-in filter option, which can be used ad-hoc.

First, you'll need to form a table.. then just click the filter arrows.

Comment: Yes, I am using Excel 2010 but the reason for wanting to write VBA code is because the workbook is immense and, as such, I will have to constantly navigate back to the relevant section, apply the filter, then navigate back to whence I came.  Subsequently, the feature you describe can be used across many previous iterations of Excel, but this is not feasible enough for me as I require my own custom button (I have developed a large quantity of useful custom buttons (which run macros) that perform my most frequently used tasks). Thank you all the same.